# QI-closure of $\mathrm{NA}\times\mathrm{NA}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Suppose we know the following about a class of groups $\mathcal{G}$.

1. If $G$, $H$ are f.g. r.p. nonamenable groups, then $G \times H \in \mathcal{G}$.
2. If $G \in \mathcal{G}$, $G$ is f.p., and $G$ is quasi-isometric to $H$, then $H \in \mathcal{G}$.

Here, f.g. means finitely generated, f.p. means finitely presented, r.p. means recursively presented.

> What interesting/surprising/non-trivial corollaries can we deduce?

The motivation for this question is that I have a class for which I believe I can prove 1 and 2, so I'd like to know what interesting things my class contains just based on that. I already know a very interesting corollary, namely that my class contains a simple group [Burger-Mozes](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1839489). Unbelievable! Are there other surprises?

If it simplifies things, don't get too hung up on the r.p. and f.p. details. For instance if you can say something about the title, i.e. QI-closure of $\mathrm{NA}\times\mathrm{NA}$.

Comment: There appear to be at least three ([1](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1446574) [2](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1839489) [3](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3291248)) "Burger–Mozes"s.  Which one is the relevant one here?

Comment: Axiom 2 sounds weirdly stated, since $H$ QI to $G$ fp implies $G$ fp. So you have an isomorphism-closed class $\mathcal{G}$ of groups such that its subclass of fp elements is QI-closed, and contains all direct products of 2 fg rp non-amenable groups. The smallest class satisfying thus consists of (a) the fp groups QI to such a fp product (b) the rp fg direct products of two non-amenable groups. Probably the last formulation of the question is better

Comment: @LSpice in this case it probably means simple f.p. groups that occur as acting geometrically on a product of two trees. Other interesting groups QI to a product of non-amenable groups (and not virtually directly decomposable) are various irreducible lattices in products of Lie or non-archimedean groups. Rataggi also produced groups QI to a product of two bushy trees, that have no proper finite index subgroups, but have many normal subgroups of infinite index.

Comment: BTW "interesting" obviously depends on how your class is defined... I somewhat have the guess that your class is that of groups that admit a strongly aperiodic subshift, or something of this spirit, but this is hard to guess a priori...

Comment: I added the correct BM reference, the deduction is on page 760 of Drutu-Kapovich.

Comment: @YCor does your class of interesting examples include some where the group is QI to a product of two nonamenables, but you use something other than two trees?

Comment: Regarding last comment of @YCor, I think knowing the exact class doesn't affect the sort of things I'd consider interesting, and does not help suggesting groups in the class. You guess the spirit correctly (though I nitpick that all countable groups admit a SA subshifts, and not all products of f.p. nonamenable groups admit SA SFTs).

Comment: @YCor: On second thought, of course you are right, if some group in this class is one for which strongly aperiodic SFTs are not previously known, that's interesting, since indeed my condition implies that. Mainly non-RF Baumslag-Solitar groups spring to mind, are they QI to products of NA? I know they are a single QI-class, but I don't know what else is there.

Comment: Ok, I found the understandable classification of those (QI to $\mathrm{BS}(2,3)$ groups). I'll look at this subquestion. The main question was more or less successful: I have not missed anything *completely* obvious.

Comment: @VilleSalo a Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(m,n)$ with $|m|\neq |n|$ has a 1-dimensional asymptotic cone. Hence a direct product of two infinite f.g. groups cannot embed QI into it. In particular it cannot be QI to such a direct product.

Comment: Am I correct that even by repeatedly passing to subgroups and taking QI groups you cannot find such a product?

Comment: I.e. can distorted subgroups cause a problem

Comment: (I don't really understand your claim about the asymptotic cone, I suggested QI+subgroups cannot give you products due to some Bass-Serre theory arguments I spotted in the literature (and which I don't fully understand either).)